# getting module not found error after deploying flask app to heroku server

Tags: python, flask, heroku, module, gunicorn

so i had this flask app running successfully on my `Heroku server`. i just added `contact form` functionality to my flask app and everything was working fine on `my local machine` but after deploying the app on `heroku`, it's giving me errors. I've checked the `heroku logs` and the error's looks like this:

```
from forms import ContactForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

**app.py (just the importing part)**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from forms import ContactForm
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField, TextField
from wtforms import ValidationError, validators

class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    name = TextField("Name", [validators.Required("Please enter your fullname")], render_kw={"placeholder" : "Fullname"})
    email = TextField("Email", [validators.Required("Please enter your email adrress"), validators.Email()], render_kw={"placeholder" : "Emaill"})
    subject = TextField("Message", [validators.Required("Enter your subject")], render_kw={"placeholder" : "Subject"})
    message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required("Enter your message")], render_kw={"placeholder" : "Message "})
    send_message = SubmitField("Send")
```

**My folder structure**

[image]

**Procfile**

`web: gunicorn app.app:app`

Answer (score 1):

ok so now i've figured it out. I just changed the folder structure to something like this:

**Project structure**

[image: folder structure]

Hope it will help others in future.